# Calculating the joint cumulative distribution function from a junction tree

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions, copula

Assume I have the following [Junction Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_tree_algorithm) between random variables $X_1,\dots,X_7$ that exactly describes the sets variables with non-zero [Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) (Alternatively it's the last tree in a [Truncated Vine Sequence](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X15000470)).

[image]

Where the nodes with circles are the **clusters** of the Junction Tree, and the nodes with squares are the **separators** of the Junction Tree.

According to [this paper](https://repozitorium.omikk.bme.hu/bitstream/handle/10890/3880/82639.pdf?sequence=1) and formula ($4.1$), I can then calculate their [Joint Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution). However, I'm having difficulties understanding the formula. Would it be correct to say that for the tree above, we can write up this formula:

$$\begin{matrix} & & \mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_3\le x_3,X_6\le x_6)\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_4\le x_4,X_6\le x_6) \\ & & \mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_4\le x_4,X_5\le x_5)\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_2\le x_2,X_4\le x_4) \\ & & \mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_2\le x_2,X_7\le x_7)\\ 
\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_7 \le x_7)& = & \frac{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}{} \\
& & \mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_6\le x_6)\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_4\le x_4)^2\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_2\le x_2) \end{matrix}$$

(Everything is multiplied together in the nominator, I just didn't have enough space; and the $\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x_1,X_4\le x_4)$ term in the denominator is squared because it appears twice.)

**So my question is:**
Is the above formula correct? Or is it perhaps only applicable for joint **density**/**weight** functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found the answer for my question:

No, the formula isn't correct, you can generate counterexamples where it doesn't hold. However it *is* true if we replace every $\le$ sign with an $=$ sign.